# Change field name and edit a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I have a csv file I am looking at in bash that I am trying to manipulate. There are several things that I have/am trying to edit. Structure is like so where the first row are the column(field) headers

```
cat,dog,hippopotamus,zebra
1,,3,2
three species, five species,only one,multiple
at,home, at, home, wild, wild
```

1. How can I edit the field (column) names in the csv?

   ```
   head -1 test.csv
   ```

   shows what the field (column) names are, but it still has the commas in it as well and this doesn't allow for field name changing at all.

   The other part about this is that I want to only edit titles that are greater than 8 characters in length, in which case I will just take the first 8 characters. I'm guessing I would use some sort of loop based on string length but since I don't know how to even edit the field name of just one column I'm not sure how to do this. In scenario above, changing `hippopotamus` to `hippopot`.
2. How can I replace empty cells in the csv to `NA` or `NULL`?

   ```
   sed -i 's/ /NULL/g'
   ```

   Thought would work but doesn't.
3. Some of the cells have commas within them, messing with the `,` delimiter. I used the code below and it seems to work, but is there a better/safer way to do this?

   ```
   sed -i "s/, /_/g"
   ```
4. Or in a similar situation, if multiple columns contain strings sometimes with spaces within a string but I only want to remove the space in one of the columns while leaving the other columns alone, how can I achieve this?

   ```
   sed -i 's/ //g' test.csv
   ```

Comment: If a field name contains commas, how is determined what belongs to which field? are the fields not quoted? Otherwise that's not properly "comma separated".

Comment: Everything you want to do is absolutely trivial in awk and has been solved a thousand times on this site and others, just google it. Having said that - your posted sample input doesn't make sense, see the comment from @BenjaminW.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sed will allow a line number as a command prefix, to only work on a single line (or a range of numbers, to work on lines in that range). Try something like this.

   ```
   sed -e '1s/cat/Feline/' test.csv > test2.csv
   ```
2. CSV files will store an empty field as either a comma at start of line, a comma at end of line, or a comma followed by another comma:

   ```
   Field1,Field2,Field3
   ,"<-- empty field1",field3
   field1,,"<-- empty field2"
   field1,"empty field3-->",
   ```

   You can use the following `sed` commands to fix these:

   ```
   sed -e 's/^,/NA,/;s/,$/,NA/' -e ':loop' -e 's/,,/,NA,/g;tloop' test.csv
   ```
3. Your solution appears good. Be aware, however, that CSV should have quotes around any string containing a comma. And that's legit. It's also the point where `sed` stops being a good tool for manipulating CSV files. ;-) One suggestion would be to replace "interior" commas with "%2C", which is the HTML encoding for a comma. That's pretty distinctive, and at least somewhat standard.
4. `sed` numbers groups starting from the left-most paren. If your groups match multiple times, you can only get the last match contents, but if an outer group contains the multi-match, the outer group is still valid. (I assume here that you have already replaced the "interior" commas with something else.)

   ```
   sed -e ':loop' -e '^\(\([^,]*,\)\{3\}\)\([^ ,]*\) /\1\3/;tloop'
   ```

   This will remove the first space in column 4, then loop. It will stop when it finds the comma that ends the column, or end-of-line.

   Note that the first part, called `\1`, is general. You can replace the 3 with whatever field, minus one, and that will get you to the start of the field. The actual work is in the second part, `\3`, where you can do what you like. (Note that `\2` is included within `\1`, and not particularly useful.)